# How to prove $\lim_{x\to 0}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^{-2k}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, power-series

How to prove $$\lim_{x\to 0}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^{-2k}=0$$ as if you do not recognize it as $e^{-1/x^2}$?

---

My attempt:

I can come up with an approach, which poorly pretends that I know nothing about $e^{-1/x^2}$.

Let $$f(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{x^{-2n}}{n!}$$

Then, $$f(x) \cdot \sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^{-2k} = \sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{n!k!}x^{-2(n+k)}$$

The coefficient of $x^{-2j}$ ($j\in\mathbb N$) on the right hand side is
$$[x^{-2j}]=\sum^j_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(j-n)!}=\frac1{j!}\sum^j_{n=0}\binom{j}{n}(-1)^n(1)^{j-n}=\frac1{j!}(-1+1)^j=0$$

(Note that binomial theorem is utilized.)

Also, $[x^0]=1$. Hence,

$$\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^{-2k} =\frac1{f(x)}$$

We then have $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)>\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1{x^2}=+\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1{f(x)}=0$$
and so does the series.

*Clearly I know something about $e^{-1/x^2}$, otherwise I would not have been able to define such a nice $f(x)$ that multiplies with the series to give $1$.*

---

The simplest answer will be accepted.

**NB: I am looking for alternative methods.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following proof proceeds by studying the differential equation associated to the function $f$. I tried my best so that the proof employs the standard ideas in the theory of ordinary differential equation.

- By the substitution $z = x^{-2}$, it suffices to consider the function

  $$ g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} z^n $$

  and then investigate the limit of $g(z)$ as $z\to+\infty$. To this end, notice that $g$ satisfies the differential equation

  $$ g'(z) = -g(z). \tag{DE}$$
- Now assume that $g \geq 0$ on $[a, b]$ for some $a < b$. By the Mean Value Theorem,

  $$ g(a) - g(b) \stackrel{\exists \xi \in (a,b)}{=} -g'(\xi)(b-a) \stackrel{\text{(DE)}}{=} g(\xi)(b-a). $$

  Also, $\text{(DE)}$ shows that $g$ is non-increasing on $[a, b]$, and so, $g(a) \geq g(\xi) \geq g(b)$ holds. Plugging the above equality to this and rearranging, we get the following implication

  $$ g \geq 0 \text{ on } [a, b] \quad \Rightarrow \quad (1-(b-a))g(a) \leq g(b) \leq \frac{g(a)}{1+(b-a)}. \tag{1}$$

  In particular, if $b-a < 1$ and $g(b) = 0$, then $\text{(1)}$ shows that $g(a) = 0$ as well, hence $g \equiv 0$ on $[a, b]$.
- We show that $g > 0$ on all of $[0, \infty)$. Assume otherwise. Since $g(0) = 1$, this implies that $g$ has a positive zero. Since $g$ is continuous, we can find the smallest positive zero of $g$, which we call $\alpha$. Since $g \geq 0$ on $[0, \alpha]$, $\text{(1)}$ allows to find a positive zero of $g$ smaller than $\alpha$, a contradiction. This shows that the claim is true.
- By $\text{(1)}$ applied to $[0, x]$, we have $ 0 < g(x) \leq \frac{g(0)}{1+x} $. Then by the squeezing theorem, $g(x) \to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, and we are done.

Comment: There are a lot to digest...please give me some time.

Comment: Why does $g(0)=1\implies \text{existence of positive zero of $g$}$?

Comment: @Szeto, At that step, we assumed the negation of the claim '$g > 0$ on $[0,\infty)$', and so, we know that $g(x) \leq 0$ for some $x \geq 0$. Since $g(0) =1 > 0$, we know that any such $x$ must be positive. Then, the Intermediate Value Theorem guarantees the existence of positive zero of $g$.

Comment: I finally understand your answer. I think there might be a simpler method to prove $g$ is positive. Anyway, a marvellous answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Szeto, Thank you for accepting my answer! I suspect that there is certain trade-off between brevity and lack of knowledge. Also, if we cheat a little bit, we can check that $g(z) = g(z/2)^2 = \cdots = g(z/2^n)^{2^n}$, which together with $g(0) = 1$ will immediately establish the positivity of $g$.

Comment: That makes sense; this is the price that must be paid.